# How to use match expression instead of switch expression

Tags: php, php-8

We can use match expression instead of switch case in PHP 8.

How to write match expression correctly for the following switch case?

```
switch($statusCode) {
  case 200:
  case 300:
    $message = null;
    break;
  case 400:
    $message = 'not found';
    break;
  case 500:
    $message = 'server error';
    break;
  default:
    $message = 'unknown status code';
    break;
}
```

Comment: Did you read this: https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-match-or-switch ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an important thing that must remember with `match`. It is **type sensitive**, not as a `switch` statement. Thus it's very important to cast the variable properly. In the case of HTTP codes often it is sent in string format, e.g. `"400"`.

It may give a lot of pain during debugging when we don't know about it. If `$statusCode` was a string, the default option would be always invoked. My modified version of an accepted answer:

```
$message = match((int) $statusCode) {
  200, 300 => null,
  400 => 'not found',
  500 => 'server error',
  default => 'unknown status code',
};
```