# Is there an operator in PHP that works like switch/case?

Tags: php

I have a faint, faint memory that I have seen a solution for using ternary-like operators that works like a switch/case-statements in PHP. I *may* have seen it as an suggestion for future versions of PHP... I'm not sure, and I cannot find where I may have read it... or if my memory totally pranks me :)

The solution looked similar to this (the syntax is not correct though, I hope you understand anyway):

```
$weekday = $dayofweek ! 1 => "Monday", 2 => "Tuesday", ... , 7 => "Sunday" : "Unknown";
```

The alternative is to write...

```
switch ($dayofweek) { 
    case 1: $weekday = "Monday";  break;
    case 2: $weekday = "Tuesday"; break;
    ...
    case 7: $weekday = "Sunday";  break;
    default: $weekday = "Unknown";
}
```

(I am aware of that I can use arrays in this simple example.)

Does this operator based version of switch/case really exist? Or... have I remembered wrong? :)

Comment: Sounds like you're thinking of [match expression](https://kinsta.com/blog/php-8/#match-expression) that was introduced in PHP 8.

Comment: I think that it would be messy to have that type of syntax.
(You can have chained conditions in one line, but again, it would be a mess).
If the case is for weekdays, you can set an array of days or use the dedicated parameter of the "date()" function to retrieve day name.

Comment: Ah... thanks @MagnusEriksson! I thought that I've seen it... That's what I looked for. I remembered it as an operator, but it was en expression syntax instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use match expression instead of switch expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62983592/how-to-use-match-expression-instead-of-switch-expression) - Just so we can close it as a dupe that already has an explanation how it works.

Comment: `match` probably has advantages but similar to `$weekday = [1 => "Monday", 2 => "Tuesday", 7 => "Sunday"][$dayofweek] ?? "Unknown";`